# Create shapes based on Multipicklist values using D3.js & Apex Imperatively in a LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, data-designer, d3

I am trying to create shapes depending on the values selected on my multipicklist fields.

On my record Patient Journey, I am able to select steps and sub-steps.

Let's say I select 3 steps on the record, then I would like my LWC to create 3 shapes with the name of the 3 values selected.
If I select 1 value then, it should only create 1 shape.

[image]

Calling Apex imperatively and using d3 js, I am able to create a rectangle shape and retrieve the values of the field Steps.
My first issue is that I am not able to retrieve the value individually. I am only able to get all the values separated by semicolon

Second issue, is that I really don't know how to create a shape for each value. Currently, that's what my component looks like.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is this:
[image]

If someone could explained me how to split the values and append them a d3 shape to create as many shapes as values selected that would be great.
I have been working on this code for a week and I really don't know how to move forward. I'm really stuck.
Thanks for any help I can get

Here is my LWC Component

**.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Patient Journey" icon-name="custom:custom19">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <svg
            class="d3"
            width={svgWidth}
            height={svgHeight}
            lwc:dom="manual"
        ></svg>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

**.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import D3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/d3js';
// import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';import getAccountAndContacts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountWithContactsController.getAccountAndContacts';
import getPatientJourney from '@salesforce/apex/PatientJourneyController.getPatientJourney';

export default class PatientJourneyLibsD3 extends LightningElement {
    svgWidth = 800;
    svgHeight = 500;
    d3Initialized = false;
    @api recordId;
    @track patient_journey;
    force = '';
    @track svg;
    // noError;
    // errorMsg;

renderedCallback() {
    if (this.d3Initialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.d3Initialized = true;

    Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, D3 + '/d3.v5.min.js'),
            loadStyle(this, D3 + '/style.css')
        ])
        .then(() => {
            this.initializeD3();

        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading D3',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
}

initializeD3() {
    const svg = d3.select(this.template.querySelector('svg'));
    const width = this.svgWidth;
    const height = this.svgHeight;
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeDark2);

    getPatientJourney({
        recordId : this.recordId
    })

       .then(result => {
            let nodes=[];
            let links=[];
            for(let i=0; i<result.length; i++) { //be79ff 7dc5c4 2e90ff ffc807
                nodes.push({id:result[i].Steps__c,group: 1,label:result[i].Steps__c,color: "#2e90ff"});
            }
            console.log('nodes ',nodes);

            const simulation = d3
                .forceSimulation()
                .force(
                    'link',
                    d3.forceLink().id(d => {
                        return d.id;
                    })
                    .distance(function (d) {
                        return 151;
                    })
                    
                )
                .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
                .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
                .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(71).iterations(10))

            const step =' New Diagnostic';
            const node = svg
                .selectAll('rect')
                .data(nodes)
                .enter()
                .append('g')   
                .attr('class', 'nodes');

                node.append('rect')
                .attr('x', -350)
                .attr('y', -200)
                .attr('width', 250)
                .attr('height', 40)
                .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.color; });
                node.append("text")
                .attr('dx', -230)
                .attr('dy', -180)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) { return d.label; });
                
                simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', ticked);

                function ticked() {
                    // link.attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
                    //     .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
                    //     .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
                    //     .attr('y2', d => d.target.y)
                        //.attr('x3', d => d.target.x)
                        //.attr('y3', d => d.target.y);
                        //node.attr('cx', d => d.x).attr('cy', d => d.y);
                        node.attr("transform", function (d) {
                            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                        });
                    
                }

       })
       .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });

}


}
```

Comment: So multi-picklist is `always` separated by `;`. So you can always do (in javascript) `result[i].Steps__c.split(';')` which will give you the array of your values.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if it is up to you, I'd recommend you look at Konva js before going to D3 -> while d3 is a lot more powerful it may be quite an overkill for something as simple as this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation